# Create newable class from library

Tags: mongoose, typescript

I'm at a loss of how to properly describe this so let me work out an example. I have a library that returns a function to use as a constructor:

```
var userTemplate = lib.User;
var user = new userTemplate();
```

I'd like to strongly type this `userTemplate` as a class because I know what properties it will have. I'd like to also be able to in other parts of the application do stuff like `var user = new userTemplate()` and have the `user` object be of some known type.

I feel like I need to use ambient class declarations here, but I'm not sure how to assign the ambient declaration the reference to the actual builder?

For example, I want something like this:

```
export class Storage{
    init(){

        // somehow define that when you 
        // new a User to call this function

        User = lib.User; 
     }
}

declare class User{
   public name:string;
}
```

Basically I want to somehow define where is the code to declare the actual user. From what I understand about ambient declarations, they are specified "elsewhere". I can't figure out where this "elsewhere" actually is.  I checked one of the [typescript examples](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#samples/imageboard/db.ts) but I don't see how the mongodb ambient declaration is ever mapped to actual implementation.

I feel like I'm missing a piece of the puzzle here.

### EDIT (with specifics)

Let me get specific here:

I am trying to use strongly type mongoose.  Imagine I have a Schema class:

```
export class Schema{
    public UserData:User;

    constructor(){
        var mongoose:IMongooseBase = require("mongoose");
        var mongooseSchema = <MongooseSchema>mongoose.Schema;


        var user = new mongooseSchema({
            name: String
        });

        this.UserData = mongoose.model("User", user);
    }
}

export declare class User extends MongooseBase{
    constructor(item:any);
    public _id: string;
    public name: string;
}


declare class MongooseBase {
    findOne(item:any, callback:ICallback) : void;
    find(id:string, callback?:ICallback) : IChainable;
    save(item: IEmptyCallback) : void;
    remove(item:any, callback:IErrorCallback) : void;
    push(item:MongooseBase):void;
}

interface IMongooseSchema{
    ObjectId:String;
}

declare class MongooseSchema implements IMongooseSchema{
    constructor(item:any);
    public ObjectId:String;
}
interface IMongooseBase{
    model(name:String, ref:any):any;
    Schema():any;
}
```

Mongoose's model function gives me a function to use as a constructor.  Creating any new model type with this object will have properties defined in `MongooseBase` (such as find, findOne, etc).  I also want this user to have the user properties defined as part of the schema defined in the ambient class `User` (name).

So, for example, in javascript this akin to

```
var userProxy = mongoose.Schema("User", user);

var userData = new userProxy();
```

The user object contains inherited properties from whatever mongoose gives you (which I've mapped to the `MongooseBase` definitions). It also gives you properties that you passed in as part of the initial schema creation (when I defined `user`).

I want to be able to strongly type this proxy,like this

```
var user:UserData = new schema.UserData();
```

If I do this the typescript compiler crashes with the following exception, leading me to believe that I'm doing something insanely wacky and probably not right:

```
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:24488
                throw err;
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'construct' of null
    at TypeFlow.typeCheckNew (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:20675:27)
    at CallExpression.typeCheck (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:1275:33)
    at TypeFlow.typeCheck (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:18505:28)
    at TypeChecker.typeCheckWithContextualType (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:15909:27)
    at TypeFlow.typeCheckBoundDecl (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:18647:38)
    at VarDecl.BoundDecl.typeCheck (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:1631:29)
    at ASTList.typeCheck (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:1016:55)
    at TypeFlow.typeCheck (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:18505:28)
    at TypeFlow.typeCheckFunction (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:19815:22)
    at FuncDecl.typeCheck (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:1783:29)
```

### Edit 2

So the way I have it set up I don't get any errors in webstorm, and the generated code for other files does work properly (it matches the javascript I would've written myself), but the typescript compiler crashes and won't updated the file where I am using the references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to declare your library and your constructor function within it (modeled as a class below).  Is this what you are looking for?

```
declare module lib {
  export class User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    getChildren(): User[];
  }
}

var userTemplate = lib.User;
var user = new userTemplate();
user.name = "dave";
```

Typically your declaration for your library would be in a .d.ts file that you reference.

Let me know if I understood your question correctly.

### EDIT after further info

OK.  I'm not familiar with Mongoose, but let me see if I am understanding correctly here (after taking quick look at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html)

- You have a schema defined by a property bag where the key is a name, and the value is a type, i.e. { name: String, age: Number}.
- You pass this to mongoose.Schema, and it returns a new document 'schema'.
- You pass this to mongoose.model (along with a name) and get back a Constructor for new 'documents' that match this schema
- You can then 'new' up documents via this constructor of the schema outlined.
- The object returned also has common mongoose document methods such as "save" & "find" for datastore operations.

This is interesting as the Schema boils down to a structural type outline, similar to an interface in TypeScript, specified in an almost JSON like syntax, passing primative constructor functions to specify type (Number, String, Date, etc...).  However as TypeScript types are purely annotations that don't exist in the emitted JavaScript, you can't reuse them (and they have different types like ObjectID).

Once we get generics in the language, there we be smarter ways to do this and flow document types through find, save, etc...,  but below is the simplest way I could think to type this currently.  Is this more in-line with what you're after?

```
// Let's type it as any for now
declare var mongoose: any;

// Base interface that any 'document' will have
interface mongooseBase {
    find: (callback: { (err: any, items: any[]): void; }) => void;
    save: (hanlder: { (err: any): void; }) => void;
}

// This is the structure our 'person' document will have
interface person extends mongooseBase {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    children: { name: string; dependent: bool; }[];
};

// Need to provide the same structure in 'mongoose' style format to define.
var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String, age: Number, children: [{ name: String, dependent: Boolean }] });

// Get back a constructor function.  We assert that the type returned is a 'newable' Function (a constructor), and will return a 'person' type when called
var Person = <{ new (): person; }>mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

// Let's create one
var p1 = new Person();

// Let's set a property
p1.name = "Dave";

// Let's save Dave
p1.save(function (err) { /*TODO*/ });
```

Comment: Hmm, close but not quite. The issue is that this constructor function can be used to generate different kinds of objects. I didn't really mention that in the original question so I will provide an edit to explain further

Comment: Bill, an interesting thing now that I'm playing with your example.  If you strongly type p1 to be something else, lets say a string: `var p1:string = new Person()` the typescript compiler lets this happen no problem.  Why is that?